# MetalKit iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

Технологию Metal портировали в os x 10.11.Теперь я могу писать с помощью  metal для os x.Но запустить  ios симулятор до сих пор не получается.Почему? "no such module MetalKit".Хотя он теперь существует же.

Answer (score 1):

Metal фреймворк не доступен на симуляторе. Попробуйте запуститься на девайсе.